# Does Visual Studio Code's Webview API support innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, visual-studio-code, webview

I'm building a VSCode extension which uses webview to display dynamic data using javascript and `innerHTML`. I found that the code is working properly in Chrome, but the `innerHTML` section does not work in VS Code webview.

HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div id="root">
        Root
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('root').innerHTML += '<div>Inner HTML Success</div>'
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the extension code:

```
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('my-extension.openFileInWebview', async (url: string) => {
        const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
            'catCoding',
            'Cat Coding',
            vscode.ViewColumn.One,
            {}
        );

        const filePath = path.join(context.extensionPath, 'src', 'webviews', 'innerHtml.html');
        const fileContents = await readFile(filePath);
        const html = fileContents.toString();
        panel.webview.html = html;
    });
```

## In VS Code

[image: innerHTML not loading in VS Code]

## In Chrome

[image: innerHTML is working in Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` is supported. [Just that Javascript is disabled in webview by default](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#scripts-and-message-passing), and needs to be enabled using `enableScripts: true` option.

```
        const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
            'catCoding',
            'Cat Coding',
            vscode.ViewColumn.One,
            {
                enableScripts: true
            }
        );
```